# Alternative design pattern to Observer for .Net

Tags: c#, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I was initially going to implement an observer pattern in C# 3.0 to solve my problem although it wouldn't be implement exactly in the same way.

My problem is that I have a web application with users who can post messages. Notifications do not go directly to other users but to a distributed cache where a statistics objects are updated and users can check the statistics a decide if they want the updates or not.

I currently have a IObserver interface that would need to implement multiple Update() methods based on who is posting a message and how they do it.

I have also looked at the mediator pattern but I don't think it is a correct fit because instances of a mediator would not have a list of who is currently logged in.

I am now wondering if there is another established design pattern that would be more suitable or if I should just fuinish building out my current Observer pattern to fit my needs.

Thanks

Comment: This article on msdn gave me a better idea of what the answers below explained. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954621.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you implement it via events/delegates? This is the standard way to implement the Observer pattern in C# and other .Net languages.

Comment: Events may be the earliest implementation of the "observer", but they're deficient in many ways.  The worst of these is the lack of any good mechanism for dealing with subscription lifetime if the publisher or subscriber is abandoned [a subscription should become void if either the publisher or subscriber is abandoned].  Other patterns can provide mechanisms for alleviating these problems.

Comment: @supercat - At 2009, there were no reactive extensions, no `Obeserver`/`Observable` within the BCL and events was it if you didn't care to roll out your own.

Comment: @Oded: Fair enough, although rolling one's own wasn't overly difficult.  I do wish events had, from the beginning, been implemented by having a "subscribe" method that returns an `IDisposable`.  There wouldn't have to be any special 'event' type; the "subscribe" would be a method like any other.  Such a pattern would have made it easy for classes to allow asynchronous event subscription (if an attempt is made to dispose an object at an time when the publisher is busy, have it set a flag in itself and in the event publisher to say that's happened; the publisher could then...

Comment: ...clean up the event at its convenience).  I wonder what real advantages are achieved by having the "event" type as such?

Comment: @supercat - Don't have an answer for you. The designers and architects of .NET may have an answer (though this may be VB6 legacy)

Comment: @Oded: I am aware of nothing even remotely resembling .net events in vb6.  From what I remember, if one had a `Button` named `Foo`, clicking `Foo` would cause the system to execute method `Foo_Click` if it existed (and do nothing if not); if one had an array of buttons called `Bar()`, clicking any would cause `Bar_Click` to be invoked, passing an extra parameter to specify which button.  My guess is that a lot has to do with the fact that delegates and arrays were the only quasi-generic types in early versions of .net; a lot of ugliness stems from the initial lack of generics.

Answer (score 3):

Aren't .Net events just observer-patterns in disguise? :) You could have a class, say, Statistic, and have that class expose an OnUpdate() event.

Comment: Having to null-check your event's delegate before invoking it strikes me as being forced to look over your shoulder to ensure that someone is watching you. Which seems pretty weird conceptually.

Comment: Agreed, always hated that as well :)

Comment: @al7ut9ov8my4wopt5ur6ais5: Giving the backing field for an event delegate is given the same name as the event itself was IMHO a major misstep in the design of C#.  The backing field should have been given another name, and attempting to use the event name like a method call should have auto-generated the "execute if not null else do nothing" behavior; an attempt to assign null to the event name or compare it to null should have operated on the baking field.  An event name should not otherwise be considered synonymous with the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

C# has taken a design pattern and made it a first class citizen of the language.  Why not simply use what is provided?  I don't see anything in your example that cannot be done with the built in event structure in C#.

Comment: I'm not against using events, but I do want to keep from having any bidirectional dependency between a User and a Class that would implement the statistics update.

Comment: There is no dependency. One class exposes an event, another handles it.  The pattern reduces the need for coupling/dependencies between classes.

Comment: @EdS.: In a proper observer pattern, an event publisher should not prevent the subscriber from being garbage-collected (there are situations where an event subscriber could do something useful without any reference existing to it; but those are today probably best handled by having the subscriber use `ConditionalWeakTable` to attach its lifetime to that of things that might care about it).  Events are a major source of memory leaks in .net.

Comment: @supercat: Yup, I've fixed a couple myself.  However, I don't think it is all that common as most subscribers outlive the publisher.  like anything, you have to know what you are doing.  No abstraction is perfect.  Like you said though, a weak reference implementation is preferable.